# Compile an ASP.Net in a WinForms application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, compilation, httplistener

I'm trying to develop an agent/client that will listen to HTTP requests on a given port, and serve a simple ASP.Net page. To that end, I'm using the HttpListener and ApplicationHost classes.

I've added a simple page to my project (mypage.aspx). When it contained all the code in the single file, all worked well (tested it by adding `<% Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString()); %>` to the HTML in the page, and observing the timestamp in the browser).

I then proceeded to add a single button to it, add a code-behind file (mypage.aspx.cs) and created a designer file (mypage.aspx.designer.cs) manually. I've added `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  Codebehind="SearchForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNameSpace.MyPage" %>` to the .aspx file and verified all compiles well.

When trying to access the web page from the browser, I get the following error:

> **Description**: An error occurred during
>   the parsing of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review
>   the following specific parse error
>   details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message**: Could not load
>   type
>   'MyNameSpace.MyPage'.
>
> **Source Error**:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#"
>   AutoEventWireup="true" 
>   Codebehind="MyPage.aspx.cs"
>   Inherits="MyNameSpace.MyPage"
>   %>

I [found out](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306155) that this means my code-behind has not been compiled, or that that application cannot find the assembly. All my "bin" directory contains is the .exe and .pdb of my original application - no .dll for the .aspx.

I tried the solution offered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508689/asp-net-web-application-compiling-cs-files) and verified my .aspx and .cs files were marked for "compile" build action - to no avail.

My question is: how do I cause an .aspx file to compile in a regular WinForm application? Can I do it, or will I have to resort to adding a web application to my solution?

Comment: So your winforms application is basically the Aspnet runtime?  I would think you would need to host the aspx page on an actual web server.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using IIS. Anyway, my initial attempt (simple, on-page asp code) worked, proving I do not need IIS. I still believe it's a compilation/location issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Cassini. It's a web server that has been build awhile back by the ASP.NET team to allow Visual Studio to debug web applications without needing IIS. It's also a standalone web server. The source can be found on Dmitry's blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2006/03/09/548131.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jason, but I do not need a web server - I have the HTTPListener. My problem is a compilation issue.

Comment: If you check out how they handle the compilation, it might help.